# PHP glob images in sub-directories and find primary parent folder

Tags: php, jquery, directory, fancybox-2, glob

I created a dynamic gallery using PHP `glob` to read directories and the images in those directories, then generate links for each directory with hidden links to the images. This works fine.

The problems I'm trying to solve now are (1) how to get images from sub-directories, and (2) make sure the `rel` attribute is correct so they will be added to the correct gallery.

Right now I'm grabbing the `rel` by taking the image file as a variable and grabbing its parent using `basename(dirname($image))`.

This needs to be dynamic because there's no way to know what the sub-folders will be, if there will even be sub-folders or not, and how deep the sub-folders will be. Most likely the most will be 2 levels from the primary folders for each gallery in `/_samples/` folder, but I'm not sure, so it's needs to allow for any depth—then properly find the name of the gallery directory.

Not that it should matter, but I'm generating full paths for the images because FancyBox2 throws 404's when using relative paths with https.

```
<main>

    <?php
    // LIST DIRECTORIES AS LINKS & PREP FOR FANCYBOX
    define('BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    // directory name
    $directory = BASE . "/" . "_samples/";

    // get in directory
    $folders = glob($directory . "*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    $d = 0; // init dir array count
    $f = 0; // init file array count
    $folder_list = array();
    $image_list = array();
    $image_links = array();
    ?>
    <ul id="folder-list" class="cf">
    <?php
    // directories
    foreach($folders as $folder) { 
        if(is_dir($folder)) {
            array($l['directory'][$d] =  $folder);
            $d++;
            $nb = basename($folder) == "index" ? "1" : basename($folder);
            $folder_list[$nb] = '<li><a class="icon-folder fancybox-trigger" data-trigger-rel="' . basename($folder) . '" href="#">' . $nb . '</a></li>';

        } else {
            // nada
        }
    }
    ksort($folder_list);
    foreach ($folder_list as $sample_folder){
        echo $sample_folder;
    }
    ?>
    </ul>

    <div class="hidden-links" style="display:none;">
    <?php
    $folders2 = glob($directory . "*", GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_MARK);
    foreach($folders2 as $folder2){
        $image_files = glob($folder2 .'*.{jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
    }
    $image_files2 = glob($directory . '*/*.{jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($image_files2 as $image) {
        $image_name = basename($image);
        $parent_folder = basename(dirname($image));
        echo '<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-title="' . $parent_folder . ' : ' . $image_name . '" rel="' . $parent_folder . '" href="'. 'https://subdmain.mydomain.com/_samples/' . $parent_folder . '/' . $image_name . '">&nbsp;</a>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>

</main>
```

Comment: you should be using a recursive function

Comment: I wrote an article about a similar scenario, but for one-level depth directory  only, if you want to check it out in case it helps http://www.picssel.com/create-a-filtered-image-gallery-with-jquery-and-fancybox-part-2-create-image-thumbnails-with-php/

Comment: If I knew how to use a recursive function, I would, but I'm not a programmer :)
JFK, I'll check the link. much thanks.